# Survey on the Power of Non-Uniformity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, advice-and-nonuniformity

I know that BPP is in P/poly.

I know that if NP is in P/poly then $PH = \Sigma^2_p$

Question:

Is there a good survey on the power of non-uniformity? I'm basically looking for a list of known results about non-uniformity.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to cstheory. This question is cross-posted on MO, please read our [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) and the policy on cross-posting. Also although it is not required I encourage you to register an account and use a real name.